# Not getting notification for Group approver from Azure Devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, email-notifications

In Azure Devops I have created an Environment with Approvers list as group approvers. While I define as group approvers (AAD) I am not getting Email notification but if I define as individual user as approver then I am getting Email notification for the respective users successfully.

I am not sure why I am  not getting email notification for group approvers in Azure Devops Environment.

Can you please advice how to get email notification for "group approvers" in Azure Devops Environment.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue as reported [here](https://nam06.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopercommunity.visualstudio.com%2Fcontent%2Fproblem%2F1191765%2Fnotification-emails-not-sent-when-using-ad-groups.html&data=04%7C01%7Cv-edha%40microsoft.com%7Cebe6f154a2b04b0a595208d8bdbac7ec%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C637467957201073160%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C1000&sdata=ndhLHAtvp0lHeeRWj0BnrSvkrz406IrCI2z4w7iTpD0%3D&reserved=0) in Azure DevOps feedback forum, and the product group replied that “**This is the intended behavior. Azure DevOps doesn’t expand AD groups when delivering Notifications. Instead I’d suggest adding an email alias as an explicit recipient to that subscription and having that alias tie to the AD group if possible.**”

Also there is [a suggestion ticket](https://nam06.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopercommunity.visualstudio.com%2Fcontent%2Fidea%2F1091470%2Fsupport-notification-delivery-to-all-aad-group-mem.html&data=04%7C01%7Cv-edha%40microsoft.com%7Cebe6f154a2b04b0a595208d8bdbac7ec%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C637467957201083157%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C1000&sdata=%2Fd6tAaNVzJ8brjguyd5u%2Bkk%2BWYFc17p053mQeUfITvo%3D&reserved=0) to suggest this feature, you could vote or add your feedback here to increase the suggestion priority and then the product group will review your feedback.

Comment: @ravi Does my question help? If so, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235), it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at a few scenarios. We use the following symbols to denote the types of members:

I: individual user
T: nested team or group
A: mail-enabled Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) group.

A member that's an Azure AD group   The team has members I1, I2, and A1. What happens: only I1 and I2 get notified via their preferred email addresses. Members of A1 don't get notified, as Azure DevOps doesn't expand AD groups when delivering notifications

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/concepts-email-recipients?view=azure-devops